# Sudo su setting default password automatique

Tags: command-line, bash, password, sudo, su

I'm a newbie linux (Ubuntu) user and i have a question to `sudo su`,
I always like use the root in the shell for no annoying privilgies errors :)

But the problem is `sudo su` always ask me for a password and this is also annoying to me, because i'm on studying about linux so i open alots of shells and close them in short time :D

For that i tried write this little bash script :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "My_Password" | sudo su
```

And make a symbolic link to it for executing it each time i open a shell, this is less annoying, because sudo always ask me for the password and sometimes i do some mistake in it :)

But the problem is the bash script doesn't work :(
Does anyone know how to this??, or setting my password in sudo config file and it doesn't ask me anymore for the password?? :)

Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit your sudoers file, probably with a `sudo visudo` and add the line
`$USER ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`
where $USER is your own username

By the way, sudoers is in `/etc/sudoers` but it is dangerous to edit that file directly and possibly impossible unless you are root. It is better to use `visudo` since it writes to a temp file and then if everything went ok it will overwrite after it is finished writing. If vi is tricky, I suggest being VERY careful =D

Comment: glad I could help